# Start sections on odd pages Article Class

Tags: sectioning

I have tried many things to make sections start in odd pages and I can't get it to work. `\cleardoublepage` makes it to start on even numbers, and setting `openleft` on document class didn't help.

I am currently using the `article` class.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Class `article` is by default `oneside`, and doesn't make the difference between odd or even pages. Add `twoside` in the options, and use `\cleardoublepage` between sections:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\section{One}
\blindtext
\cleardoublepage
\section{two}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

If you  fear to forget it, you can add it to `\section` command by using `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\section}{\cleardoublepage}{}{}
\begin{document}
\section{One}
\blindtext
\section{two}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

which does the same thing without explicit `\cleardoublepage`.