# Start sections on odd pages Article Class + Write "this page intentionally left blank"

Tags: article, blank-page

The following code is from (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443455/201720) and it works perfectly for making sure that new sections start on odd page numbers.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\section}{\cleardoublepage}{}{}
\begin{document}
\section{One}
\blindtext
\section{two}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

How can I edit this code to also have the blank pages say "This page intentionally left blank" in the center?

I have seen various solutions, but none of them seem to be for the `article` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have borrowed `\cleartooddpage` from the memoir class which clears to the next odd page and can also put something on the skipped page.

```
% articleclearprob.tex  SE 566319
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% \cleartooddpage is from the memoir class
\newcommand{\cleartooddpage}[1][\@empty]{%
  \clearpage%
  \ifodd\c@page\else\hbox{}#1\clearpage\fi}
\makeatother
%  macro to clear to odd page and put a specific text at the centre of a skipped page
\newcommand{\leftblank}{%
  \cleartooddpage[\vspace*{\fill}\hfill This page intentionally left blank\hfill\vspace*{\fill}]}

%\pretocmd{\section}{\cleardoublepage}{}{}
\pretocmd{\section}{\leftblank}{}{}

\begin{document}
\section{One}
\blindtext
\section{two}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you very much! I am not sure if I am the only one having this issue or if I have poor eyesight, however, it seems to me that the text "This page intentionally left blank" is a bit of off the center of the page.

Comment: @Aziz It is centered on an even numbered page. It is up to you how you specify the text and its position on the skipped page.

Comment: Right... I will try to figure it out. Thank you again.